# writing under horizontal accolade in lyx

Tags: lyx

I want to write under my accolade so that I can specify my equations,I inserted the code for accolade \underbrace but I couldn't o write under the accolade [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same way you add a subscript. Move the cursor outside the inset with the underbrace, and add the subscript, e.g. with the <kbd>_</kbd> key, or the button on the toolbar.

So after adding the text with underbrace:

[image]

Hit the right arrow key <kbd>→</kbd>. Note the inner markings disappear, indicating you're outside the inset for the underbrace.

[image]

Now add the subscript, and you get this, where you type whatever text you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much sir!!!